# Using Protractor with angular formly

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-formly

I have a project in angular using formly forms 
http://angular-formly.com/#/ and want to add some end to end testing using [Protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/).

I can't select an element by the model since the form fields are defined in code not in template and when they are rendered they get different ng-model and I don't want to add specific classes since I have pretty big forms.

Is there a way to do it and test the forms rendered by Formly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to find all formly `input` elements, [evaluate](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) the model value and [filter](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
var formlyInputs = $$("input");

var desiredModel = "modelName";
var desiredInput = formlyInputs.filter(function (input) {
    return input.evaluate("model[options.key]").then(function (model) {
        return model === desiredModel; 
    });
}).first();

desiredInput.sendKeys("some text");
```

You may need to extend that to support not only the `input` elements, but other form elements a form might have.

---

Another solution would be to rely on the preceding label of an input:

```
var label = "Text";

var desiredInput = element(by.xpath("//label[normalize-space(.) = '" + label + "']/following-sibling::input"));
desiredInput.sendKeys("some text");
```

Comment: Sorry no worky :)  Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //label[normalize-space(.) = 'Title']/following-sibling::input)
I tried both ways but Protractor can't find elements on page

Comment: @vodich not sure what to add here. Just provided two general ideas, work on making them work in your specific use case. There could be multiple reasons why "no element found" error would be raised - check if the element(s) you work with is inside an iframe or not. See if this is a timing issue and u need to use `browser.wait()`..thanks.

Comment: right, could be the timing issue, Ill check it tomorow and let you know. I have pause of one second but that might not be enough since the form i rather large and data comes from different services.

Comment: Thanks it worked I just added browser.waitForAngular()